# Possible to use ActiveRecord methods on objects loaded from db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to apply the "find_all_by..." method to records that have already been retrieved by User.all. Is this possible? At this point I am getting an "undefined method `find_all_by_type" error:

```
rows = User.all
rows.each do |r|
  result = rows.find_all_by_type(r.type)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the records are loaded, you can use any `Enumerable` method on the collection.  What you're looking for here is `select`:

```
rows = User.all
rows.each do |r|
  result = rows.select {|row| row.type == r.type}
end
```

Although I do wonder what you're actually trying to do here.  If this is pseudocode or a simplified example, then you can probably apply my code above.  You may be better off with this though:

```
rows = User.all.group_by(&:type)
```

Comment: Perfect Jim. The above is pseudo. I am actually looping through each record to determine how many users have the same 'type'. With 1 mill records, a SQL solution would probably be much faster...

Comment: "Amen" on the SQL solution to that one